# How will you convert method to single line in java8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

I am having following method which converts single line to map

And want to convert it to single line statement using java8

input pipe separated string 
e.g.: 
status:MYSTATUS|data1:value1

```
public Map<String, String> getMap(String attributeUpdate){
    Map<String, String> attr = new HashMap<>();
    if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(attributeUpdate)){
        List<String> a = Arrays.asList(attributeUpdate.split("\\|"));
        for (String s : a) {
            String[] key_val = s.split(":");
            if(key_val.length == 2) {
                attr.put(key_val[0], key_val[1]);
            }
        }
    }
    return attr;
}
```

Comment: This is off topic, but I cannot see how this would improve anything. Refactoring existing and working code should be carefully considered,  and I fail to see a reason to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this following code. It works fine.

```
String s = new String("status:MYSTATUS|data1:value1");
Arrays.stream(s.split("\\|")).map(stringArray -> stringArray.split(":"))
        .filter(stringArray -> stringArray.length == 2)
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(stringArray ->stringArray[0], stringArray-> stringArray[1],(oldvalue,newvalue)->newvalue));
```

Thanks

Comment: Instead of `Arrays.asList(…).stream()` you can use `Arrays.stream(…)`.

Comment: Just a hint: `stringArray -> stringArray.split(":")` should better be named `string -> string.split(":")`, since `stringArray` is a `String`, not an array.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple solution :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

public class Test {

    @org.junit.jupiter.api.Test
    public void shouldParseAttributes() throws Exception {
        String attributeUpdate = "status:MYSTATUS|data1:value1";

        Map<String, String> attributes = Stream.of(attributeUpdate.split("\\|"))
            .map(attribute -> attribute.split(":"))
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                    attribute -> attribute[0],
                    attribute -> attribute[1]));

        assertThat(attributes).containsEntry("status", "MYSTATUS");
        assertThat(attributes).containsEntry("data1", "value1");
    }
}
```

Comment: As my curious, In your collect method have two split statement so it's compare with my solution your code have 3 split statement right?

Comment: I improved it a bit to avoid doing twice the split inside the collect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try as below,

```
Arrays.stream(attributeUpdate.split("\\|"))   //convert directly to stream
    .map(e->e.split(":"))
    .filter(e->e.length==2)
    .collect(toMap(s->s[0], s->s[1], (o, n)->n));  // collect map, handle duplicates
```